# Dynamically create page-breaks when printing for items that contain images which are taller than expected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a view that generates a HTML structure of individual client receipts.  These receipt images can be of varying heights. If a PDF is uploaded, we convert it to an image for easier rendering, but want to display each page inside its parent container.

```
<div class="expense-report">
  <table class="expenses"> /* Associated expenses table */</table>
    <ul class="receipt-list">
      <li class="receipt-block border-black multi">
        <div class="receipt-number">Receipt1</div>
        <img src="...path/to/image/page1" />
        <img src="...path/to/image/page2" />
        <img src="...path/to/image/page3" />
        <div>/* More receipt data if available */</div>
     </li>
     <li class="receipt-block border-black single">
       <div class="receipt-number">Receipt2</div>
       <img src="...path/to/image" />
       <div>/* More receipt data if available */</div>
     </li>
     <li class="receipt-block border-black single">
       <div class="receipt-number">Receipt3</div>
       <img src="...path/to/image" />
       <div>/* More receipt data if available */</div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have a requirement to add a "page-break-before" or "page-break-after" onto the "receipt-block" so the whole block will break together if an image is too large for the remaining whitespace on a page when printing/print previewing.

So, if "page1" in my example can't fit onto the first page it attempts to render on, it will break for the entire "receipt-block" and put it on a new page, which can then break wherever its heart desires.  Likewise, if "Receipt2" and "Receipt3" are small receipts, they should take up the correct space on the page without breaking (i.e. no page-break-after).

Currently, the "receipt-block" wrapper begins directly after the previous block, but the image page breaks, so I end up with "Receipt1" on one page, with a border, and a bunch of whitespace until it shows the image on the next page, when I'd like it to break the whole block when it decides the image should break.

I've tried several combinations of changing the display style, adding page-break-inside: avoid to all of the elements, using widows/orphans, changing the overflow, converting the whole structure to a table layout, etc.  When I do find a solution that seems to work, if you switch the print layout to landscape it reverts to the same issue.

Is there a way to dynamically check if an image is on a different page using JavaScript, or if it will end up page-breaking on it's own, so I can add a page break on the correct items?

Can't seem to figure out how to get this behavior, or if it's even possible? Cross-browser printing support seems to be overlooked and handled differently by browsers.

Any solutions to this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for an issue I've had before, but I don't think this is possible with Javascript.  Maybe if you had the exact height of every element in the DOM (in inches) and you page was totally static, you could iterate through the DOM and assign the appropriate elements with a class that contains `page-break-after: always` (but this seems pretty brutal). Good luck!

Comment: Glad I'm not alone in seeing this odd behavior, thanks for the vindication.  Did you ever end up solving your problem? 

I thought perhaps there might be a way to calculate the space remaining on the page and check the height of the block itself, maybe I could do something like you're suggesting but it seems improbable and like using a sledgehammer to hang a picture frame.  

The calculation route also seems bad because they could be printing on atypical sized paper...

Comment: Nope, my project had too many instances of DOM elements being hidden/shown dynamically to do any sort of manual calculation.  (Also, my suggestion is totally specious and I don't recommend it. :P )